# How to add exact values to a psobject in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, scripting

I'm doing a script in powershell where i'm modifying the Chrome Bookmarks file.
This is what i want to do.

1. Read the file and parse the Json (Done)
2. Check if a certain folder is added, if it isn't, add it.
3. Parse again the object to Json, and save a new bookmark file. (i know how to do it)

This is how i convert it to Object:

```
$BkmrkJson = Get-Content $GoogleBkmrk | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And this is how i'm adding a new Object to the current "Childrens(Urls or bookmarks)".

```
$BkmrkJson.roots.bookmark_bar.children += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{children=@();date_added="";date_modified="";guid="";id="";name="HV2";type="folder"}
```

My main problem, it's that when i add it, it isn't respecting the order of the properties. The usual order it's "children, date_added, date_modified, guid, id, name, type".

[image]

I add some values in blank, because Chrome adds new values automatically, after i add that value, or children, i parse again the psobject to Json.

```
$MyFinalJson = ConvertTo-Json $BkmrkJson -Depth 9
```

But when i create the file, it wasn't made correctly. So my principal question it's, how i can add correctly a new object to the parsed one, so when i parse it again, can recognize correctly the new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) are inherently *unordered* in PowerShell / .NET, i.e the order in which their entries are later enumerated isn't guaranteed, which means that by the time your [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) call receives its `-Property` argument, the *definition* order of the entries in the hashtable is already lost.

However, PowerShell v3+ offers *syntactic sugar* for constructing custom objects (`[pscustomobject]` (aka `[psobject]`)), in which case the order of entries, i.e. the order of the resulting properties *is* guaranteed to reflect the *definition* order, namely if you cast a hashtable to `[pscustomobject]`:

```bash
$BkmrkJson.roots.bookmark_bar.children += 
  [pscustomobject] @{
    children=@();  # Note: ";" only strictly needed in *single-line* defs.
    date_added="";
    date_modified="";
    guid="";
    id="";
    name="Humach V2";
    type="folder"
  }
```

Note that in cases where you do want to stick with a hashtable (dictionary), you can "cast" a hashtable literal to `[ordered]`, which also guarantees preserving the input order; specifically, this syntactic sugar creates an *ordered* hashtable, i.e. a [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary) instance, which also implements the [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) interface, but (a) enumerates its entries in definition order and (b) allows accessing entries by *positional index*, as an alternative to using a *key* as the index; e.g.:

```bash
$orderedHashTable = [ordered] @{ zebra = 26; quebec = 17; alpha = 1}

$orderedHashTable.Keys # -> 'zebra', 'quebec', 'alpha'

# Access by key.
$orderedHashTable['quebec'] # -> 17

# Access by positional index
$orderedHashTable[0] # -> 26 (key 'zebra')
```